# Change cursor to image

Tags: delphi

I have an TImage in my form, and i want to change cursor when the cursor on TImage. But there is no cursor in default, i want.

I load the cursor image as a resource. Its format is ".cur", i dont know is that true.

So how can i load cursor resource?

I found this code but it does not work :

```
const
   crMyCursor = 5;


procedure TformMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  imgPreview.Cursor[crMyCursor]:= LoadCursor(HInstance, 'openedhand');
  Cursor := crMyCursor;
end;
```

Error : Array type required

I want to add new image as a cursor this:
[image]

Comment: In what sense does that code "not work". Compile error. Runtime error? Doesn't do what you want? Perhaps the code works fine but it is intended to solve a completely different problem? Anyway, aren't you meant to handle this by responding to incoming `WM_SETCURSOR` messages?

Comment: `Screen.Cursors[crMyCursor] := LoadCursor(HInstance, 'openedhand'); 
imgPreview.Cursor := crMyCursor;`

Comment: thanks @TLama it works, apologize david to less information. I added more information but TLama 's answer is working. Thank you too David Heffernan